# Using react-js-pagination for pagination but bootstrap style not getting applied

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, bootstrap-4

I am using **react-js-pagination** for displaying page numbers in application. Bootstrap is added in the **public/index.html** file and is accessible using className in other components.

For Pagination component do I need to add the bootstrap style explicitly? All the examples I have seen are having the style automatically applied.

Code-

```
import Pagination from "react-js-pagination";
<Pagination
        activePage={this.state.activePage}
        itemsCountPerPage={3}
        totalItemsCount={450}
        pageRangeDisplayed={3}
        onChange={this.handlePageChange}
      />
```

Answer (score 1):

from react-js-pagination documentation:

> If you would like it to work for Bootstrap 4, you will need to add 2
>   additional props when using this component:
>   linkClass="page-link"
>   itemClass="page-item"

so you just need to do this:

```
<Pagination
    itemClass="page-item"
    linkClass="page-link"
    activePage={this.state.activePage}
    itemsCountPerPage={3}
    totalItemsCount={450}
    pageRangeDisplayed={3}
    onChange={this.handlePageChange}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks as if react-js-pagination is using bootstrap v3, you can do the following

1. Install bootstrap v3 using npm (npm install bootstrap@3 --save) or
2. Include the cdn link in public/index.html file

[Bootstrap v3 CDN](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/)